# Ant build is slow

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, ant

Hi I am using an ant build to generate Hibernate java classes but I am having trouble.

The task hbm2java is slow (10 mins and not finished yet....)

Nothing particular in logs.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx512m -Xss2m -Dant.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ant -Dant.library.dir=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2 -logger com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaAntLogger2 -inputhandler com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaInputHandler -buildfile /Users/user1/dev/project/module/hibernate_build.xml
hibernate_build.xml
Executing Hibernate Tool with a JDBC Configuration (for reverse engineering)
1. task: hbm2java (Generates a set of .java files)
```

I am using the ant plugin bundled 231.8770.65 and IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-231.8770.65, built on April 27, 2023

Here is the hibernate_build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="project_name" basedir=".">
    <path id="toolslib">
        <fileset dir="hibernate/libs">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="toolslib" />

    <hibernatetool destdir="src/main/java">
        <jdbcconfiguration packagename="packagename" detectmanytomany="true" configurationfile="hibernate/hibernate_source.cfg.xml" />
        <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true" />
        <hbm2cfgxml ejb3="true" destdir="src/main/resources" />
    </hibernatetool>
</project>
```

My co-workers use an older version of IntelliJ and it works

Comment: Does it work faster if you build the project from the command line outside of the IDE? Check if the problem is related to the antivirus configuration https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560-Antivirus-Impact-on-Build-Speed